# Extract a node with its entire content from a namespaced xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Given the following namespaced xml file:

```
<ptk:PrintTalk xmlns:ptk="http://linkToNameSpace"> xmlns:xjdf="http://linkToNamespace"
 <ptk:Request>
  <ptk:PurchaseOrder Currency="EUR">
   <xjdf:XJDF name="someName" version="2.0">
     <xjdf:ProductList>
      <xjdf:Product>
       ...
      </xjdf:Product>
      <xjdf:OtherProduct>
       ...
      </xjdf:OtherProduct> 
      and many other products
     </xjdf:ProductList>
     <xjdf:ParameterSet>
      <xjdf:Parameter>
       ...
      </xjdf:Parameter> and so on until
   </xjdf:XJDF>
  </ptk:PurchaseOrder>
 </ptk:Request>
</ptk:PrintTalk>
```

how would I extract following using XPath:

```
<xjdf:XJDF name="someName" version="2.0">
 <xjdf:ProductList>
  <xjdf:Product>
   ...
  </xjdf:Product>
  <xjdf:OtherProduct>
   ...
  </xjdf:OtherProduct> 
   and many other products
  </xjdf:ProductList>
   <xjdf:ParameterSet>
    <xjdf:Parameter>
     ...
    </xjdf:Parameter> and so on until
</xjdf:XJDF>
```

I already tried something like:

```
/ptk:PrintTalk/ptk:Request/ptk:PurchaseOrder/*
```

or

```
//xjdf:XJDF
```

but these expressions give me not the result I am looking for. I use IntellijIdea's built in xpath expression evaluator, programming language is java. No libraries for xpath - just java.xml.*

**UPDATE**

using

```
//ptk:PurchaseOrder//*
```

I get every node as a single node without any child nodes inside, e. g. would

```
<xjdf:ProductList>
 <xjdf:Product>
  ...
 </xjdf:Product>
</xjdf:ProductList> (here the product tag is a child of product list tag)
```

result in

```
<xjdf:ProuctList>
<xjdf:Product>
```

The java code I use to do the operation:

```
@Override
public XJDF readFrom(
    final Class<XJDF> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType,
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap, final InputStream inputStream
) throws IOException {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document documentPtk = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("//ptk:PurchaseOrder//*");
        Document documentXjdf = (Document) xPathExpression.evaluate(documentPtk, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("PrintTalk document could not be deserialized.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What tool/language/library are you using to execute these XPath expressions?  What output _do_ you get?  None at all, plain text without XML tags, or something else?  Remember XPath is a language for selecting nodes from an XML file, what you do with those nodes once they've been selected (print their string values, serialize them as XML, etc.) is a separate issue.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide more information. What I need to do is extract the desired content of one w3c document and create a new w3c document from the extracted content in java

Comment: Please post your Java code.

Comment: While you are using XPath anyway, let me point you to [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org). It solves a lot of issues (related to namespaces, type conversion, object mapping, IO) out of the box. You can save a lot lines of code using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three main points to make here:

- `DocumentBuilderFactory` is not namespace-aware by default, you must explicitly switch on namespaces before you create the `DocumentBuilder`
- XPath doesn't use the namespace prefix mappings from the XML document, it uses its own `NamespaceContext` instead
- The `Node` returned by this query won't be a `Document`, it'll be an `Element`.

Annoyingly there's no default implementation of `NamespaceContext` in the Java core class library so you have to either use a third party one (I usually use the [`SimpleNamespaceContext` from Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.html)) or write your own implementation of the interface.

Here's an example using `SimpleNamespaceContext`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document documentPtk = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

SimpleNamespaceContext nsCtx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
nsCtx.bindNamespaceUri("p", "http://linkToNameSpace");
xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsCtx);

XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("/p:PrintTalk/p:Request/p:PurchaseOrder/*");
Element documentXjdf = (Element) xPathExpression.evaluate(documentPtk, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer, Ian! Thanks for pointing on the namespace context to be implemented, I didn't know that before!

Comment: As the node type returned will be an element, how can I then convert it into a byte array? Transfroming it would not work, imo, as DOMSource's constructor has a Node as a parameter

Comment: @ArthurEirich you'd have to serialize it using either a no-op `Transformer` from a `DOMSource` to a `StreamResult`, or the standard DOM `LSSerializer` mechanism.  But are you sure it's necessary?  What do you need to do with the XML next?  If you are using something like JAXB or XStream to turn XML into objects then you should be able to unmarshal directly from the DOM.

Comment: I need to extract a part of the ptk document and serialize it to a byte array. Then I need to create another java class from this byte array.

Comment: @ArthurEirich in which case yes, either the `Transformer` or `LSSerializer` approaches will work, using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as the destination.